# How to add token to my php pages

Tags: javascript, jquery, token, media

I want to add token key to some php pages which provide videos content, cause some of thieves are using my media on their windows applications and make a big load on my host, so is there any way to include token key that will be checked by any script in my host to show the content or deny?
regards.

Comment: You need server side logic (like PHP) to do this. You could use cookies and store your token in `$_SESSION` to require users to log in before accessing certain content.

Comment: thank you for your fast reply 
i want to add token on the desired pages with a javascript which will check for that key if it's already writen on external pages .. is that possible ?

Comment: A secure and scalable solution could be to use JSON Web Tokens (JWT).

Comment: @PaparazzoKid may you give more explanation or links to this option as i'm new here  .. thank you

Comment: @DZSAT: Surely you're not new to Google! Try searching "JSON Web Tokens". It's quite an in-depth subject involving front-end and back-end scripts, so it's a bit hard to explain in an answer, let alone a comment. However, after you implement it, it will provide a better method of only accepting ligitimate requests to view your content. You should also look into blocking the sites that are stealing your bandwidth and try and prevent hotlinking.

Comment: Here's some articles pulled from Google: http://websec.io/2014/08/04/Securing-Requests-with-JWT.html, http://www.sitepoint.com/php-authorization-jwt-json-web-tokens/?utm_source=sitepoint&utm_medium=nextpost&utm_term=php, https://scotch.io/tutorials/the-anatomy-of-a-json-web-token, http://jwt.io/.